# Cannot solve for the variable with Solve[expression, variable] function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need to solve an equation with 1 unknown appearing in the exponent 3 times. Once launched Wolfram keeps 'running...' and never finishes the computation.

Solve[51684.2/342077 * 0.048 / 0.148 * 26.09/22.19 == 
  Exp[t/26.09] - Exp[(22.19 t - 26.09 t) / 22.19*26.09], t]

Results should be around the magnitude of 10-100 I think.

Comment: Are you aware there's a dedicated Mathematica site on Stack Exchange? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 51684.2/342077*0.048/0.148*26.09/22.19;
b = Exp[(22.19 t - 26.09 t)/22.19*26.09];
FindRoot[a == Exp[t/26.09] - b, {t, 0}]
```

> ```
> {t -> 0.0128273}
> ```

or

```
NSolve[a == Exp[t/26.09] - b, t, Reals]
```